# How to prevent overlap of percentage labels in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I want to prevent an overlap of my percentage labels in a ggplot2.

The code is here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = question, y = prop, fill = response)) +geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(prop, 2)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color="white", size = 4) +labs(title =" Which types of behaviors have you encountered \n as a driver of YOUR partly automated car? ", subtitle =" Please provide your level of agreement with the following statements.") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("1" = "#CC3300", "2" = "#FF3300", "3" = "#FF6600", "4" = "#FF9900", "5" = "#FFCC00"), labels = c("1" = "Strongly disagree", "2" = "Disagree", "3" = "Neutral", "4" = "Agree", "5" = "Strongly agree")) +labs(x = "Motives for disengaging PAD", y = "Percentage") + theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 12, face = "bold"))  +scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 360, hjust = 0, size = 10)) +theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 360, hjust = 0, size = 10)) + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Response options", size = 10)) + coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(" PAC typically \n starts to change \n lanes then returning to lane \n halfway through process"," PAC typically \n asks me to take \n over control when not \n ready to take over control"," PAC typically \n makes smooth gentle \n steering corrections"," PAC typically \n accelerates and \n decelerates smoothly"," PAC typically \n detects lane \n markings on roadway", " PAC typically \n detects car \n ahead in my lane"))
```

I added an image of the bar which clearly shows that percentage labels overlap on the left side of the image.

[image]

Comment: OP, can you post your dataset, `df` as the output of `dput(df)` within the question too?

Comment: Thanks. Here it is:

Comment: Thanks. Used the dput function but have too many characters. Any idea of an elegant way of how to provide an overview of my df?

Comment: Maybe just include a question or two?  You only need enough data to demonstrate the issue.  So, something like `dput(df[which(df$question %in% c(...)),])`